# Swift Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012

Tags: debugging, afnetworking, nsurlconnection, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I am a new student working on a summer project following my freshman year with little experience and I am getting the error

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost/donate/payment.php,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost/donate/payment.php}

when I try to run a credit card payment through stripe, the code I have is

```
 func postStripeToken(token: STPToken) {

    let URL = "https://localhost/donate/payment.php"
    let params  : [String: AnyObject] =  ["stripeToken": token.tokenId,
                                          "amount": myInt,
                                          "currency": "usd",
                                          "description": self.emailTextField.text!]

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.POST(URL, parameters: params, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in

        if let response = responseObject as? [String: String] {
            UIAlertView(title: response["status"],
                message: response["message"],
                delegate: nil,
                cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
        }

    }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
        self.handleError(error!)
    }
}
```

It wants a HTTP url instead of a `HTTPS` but when i change it to HTTP and its not secure when the user presses pay with their card they get an error

> The resource could not be loaded beach the APP Transport Security
>   Policy requires the use of a secure connection.

Is there anyway I can use a HTTPS without getting the NSURL error or I can make a secure connection without `HTTPS`?  Any Tips would be very helpful!

```
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;
```

I also tried adding this statement with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue `“The resource could not be loaded beach the APP Transport Security Policy requires the use of a secure connection”`

just write following code in your `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```